# Error using python in rmarkdown (Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) ...)

Tags: r, reticulate

I have the following rmarkdown code:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv(condaenv = "daniellgaenv", conda = r"(C:\Users\danie\anaconda3\envs\daniellgaenv)", required = TRUE)
```

```{python}
a = [1,2,3]
```
````

And it is giving me the error when running the python chunk:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: use() got an unexpected keyword argument 'warn'
```

My system infos:

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] reticulate_1.16

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2  Matrix_1.2-18   tools_4.0.2     Rcpp_1.0.5      grid_4.0.2      knitr_1.29      jsonlite_1.7.0 
[8] xfun_0.16       lattice_0.20-41
```

and from reticulate:

```
> reticulate::py_numpy_available()
[1] TRUE
> reticulate::py_config()
python:         C:/Users/danie/anaconda3/envs/daniellgaenv/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/danie/anaconda3/envs/daniellgaenv/python37.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/danie/anaconda3/envs/daniellgaenv
version:        3.7.9 (default, Aug 31 2020, 17:10:11) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/danie/anaconda3/envs/daniellgaenv/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.1

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

The same code works when working on the terminal with `repl_python`:

```
> reticulate::repl_python()
Python 3.7.9 (C:/Users/danie/anaconda3/envs/daniellgaenv/python.exe)
Reticulate 1.16 REPL -- A Python interpreter in R.
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/831

The issue should be fixed with the development version of reticulate